# How to remap :w to :up?

Tags: save, key-bindings

I have a file-watcher system which triggers some compilations upon time-stamp changes in the source file I am editing. I have the obsessive habit of using `:w` quite a few times during my editing session.

Is there a way to remap `:w` to `:up` ?

Comment: Related SO post: [vim change :x function to delete buffer instead of save & quit](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7513380/438329)

Answer (score 2):

I had added below in my .vimrc earlier based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7513380/vim-change-x-function-to-delete-buffer-instead-of-save-quit) post.

```
cnoreabbrev <expr> w getcmdtype() == ":" && getcmdline() == 'w' ? 'up' : 'w'
```

Alternatively, there is a [plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=746) which does this too.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I prefer `gecmdline() =~ '^w$'`. This way when you type `w` in the middle of the command (like when you're calling a window-local variable `w:var`) it won't expand.